# what is the fastest shield to add to the sparkfun v3.2 Arduino Uno that will enable me to playback and record hour of short audio dictation

Tags: arduino-uno

I have almost no eexperience building electronic kits. I just buoght and began tinkering with sparkfun 3.2 and want to adapt its simon sketch to real audio files
What isis theeasiest to assemble add on shield or breakout not surew hat you call this looked at this one
VS1053 Codec + MicroSD Breakout - MP3/WAV/MIDI/OGG Play + Record - v4